# How do I find an open source Ruby project to work on?

Tags: ruby, open-source

Should I just go to SourceForge and try to find something that looks interesting by doing a search? Or is there a Ruby-specific website that helps you to find open source projects to contribute to?

After you find it one, do you usually just send an email to the project owner to see if you can help or do you just start submitting code to their repository and they will take it or leave it after reviewing it for quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend going onto [github](http://www.github.com) to look for projects.  You can search around, check things out easily and its easier for the project owner to manager your changes.

Comment: Beware: a lot of Rubyists use Fossil, Monotone, Darcs or other Version Control Systems, and naturally, you won't find those projects on GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

The standard hosting site for Ruby projects is [RubyForge](https://RubyForge.Org/). Another site that is slightly older than RubyForge, is the [Ruby Application Archive (RAA)](http://RAA.Ruby-Lang.Org/). In addition to RubyForge, there are also a lot of Ruby projects hosted on [SourceForge](https://SourceForge.Net/). Projects that are specific or related to [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/), are sometimes hosted on [CodeHaus](http://Codehaus.Org/) or Sun's new project hosting site [Kenai](https://Kenai.Com/). For [IronRuby](http://IronRuby.Net/), some projects live on [CodePlex](http://CodePlex.Com/). Projects that use the [Git](http://Git-SCM.Com/) Version Control System, are often hosted on either [Gitorious](http://Gitorious.Org/) or [GitHub](https://GitHub.Com/), whereas projects that use the [Darcs](http://Darcs.Net/) Version Control System tend to be self-hosted.

However, especially larger Ruby projects often have their own infrastructure, e.g. [Merb](http://Merbivore.Com/), [DataMapper](http://DataMapper.Org/) and of course [Ruby on Rails](http://RubyOnRails.Org/).